# Postgres Format: Inserting multiple rows into Postgres with Array Column

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I have a table like below

```
CREATE TABLE test (
id UUID DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() PRIMARY KEY,
a UUID
b UUID
c TEXT[]
);
```

I am using pg-format in node to try and insert many rows into the table at once. The code for pg-format looks like below.

```
const arr = [ [uuid1, uuid2, ['str','str']] , [uuid3, uuid4, ['str','str']] , ...]
format(`
   INSERT INTO test (a,b,c)
   VALUES (%L)
`, arr)
```

This doesn't work because the format function breaks up the inputs to c (the TEXT[] column) into further elements of the outer array. IE my query ends up having more expressions than target columns. Sample Formatted query below:

```
INSERT INTO test (a,b,c)
VALUES ((uuid1, uuid2, str, str) , (uuid3, uuid4, str, str) , ...)
```

How can I use pg-format, or other means, to properly format a query like this? The total number of rows is variable as well as the length of the inner arrays for column c.

Thanks so much

Comment: I see [this](https://github.com/datalanche/node-pg-format/issues/22#issuecomment-695344164), hope it can help but it's not really practical, maybe you should use a query builder like [knexjs](https://knexjs.org/) or an orm like [prisma](https://www.prisma.io/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just formatting the string in multiple steps and the combining them as a string in the query. See below.

```
let formatted = [];
for (let row of arr){
   formatted.push(format(`(%L,%L,ARRAY[%L])`, row[0], row[1], row[2]))
}
format(`
   INSERT INTO test (a,b,c)
   VALUES %s
`, formatted)
```

Not sure if there was a better way then this but this is the best I could come up with.